# VSTS - include folder into ASP.NET Core app artifact

Tags: angular, azure-pipelines

I have an Angular 4 project (NG-p) in a separate repo. Also, I have my ASP.NET Core project (Core-p) in another repo. When Cope-p is built, it must contain NG-p artifacts. And I kind of managed to do it. Here's how it works:

- when NG-p changes, VSTS builds it and puts a zip file into Azure Storage
- Core-p gets built after that and produces ...well, something ..as part of BUILD .NET Core task
- it grabs that zip file (NG-p artifact) from Azure Storage, unzips it and puts into $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/wwwroot/js/app folder
- everything else are standard tasks - Test, Publish, Publish Artifact

Build succeeds. But when I open the artifacts, it contains:

- wwwroot folder (with all NG-p files inside)
- and myproject.zip file (everything Core-p) **<= NG-p files should be there!**

How can I have my NG-p files inside myproject.zip (and not have that separate wwwroot folder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I made it working by changing the target path in my Extract Files task to the following:

`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.Repository.Name)/wwwroot/js/app`

Now, all files are in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can both make NG-p files and Core-p files in `myproject.zip`. To make NG-p files into `myproject.zip`, you need these tasks in your Core-p build definition:

1. **Extract Files**: extract zip file in Azure and archive files in zip to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` (Destiniation Folder).
2. **Copy Files**: copy files from root of your Core-p repo into `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` (Target Folder).
3. **Archive Files**: compress files in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` folder as zip in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/myproject.zip` (Archive file to create).

[image]

4. **Publish Build Artifacts**: publish `myproject.zip` as artifact.

[image]